# Replace column with another column in CSV on Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have this code that replaces a string for another string and I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this. Instead of doing the .replace for each one, I want to just read a column and replace it with the column next to it instead of writing out .replace.

`text = open('thecode.csv','r')
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
       .replace('Salam', 'Hello') \
       .replace('somebody', 'anybody') \`

How can I go about this quicker if I have two columns that look like this:

```
Column1         Column2
Salam            Hello 
somebody         anybody
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be easier in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('thecode.csv') 
df['Column1'] = df['Column2']
df.to_csv('fixed_output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest using `Pandas`? read your file using `pd.read_csv` simply create a `Series` from your new column and replace it with the column in the correction position where you want. don't foreget to use `to_csv` at the end to write the result.